# Prevent Standard users from seeing and mounting drives

Tags: 11.10, users, fstab

My user id is 1000
and second user id is 1001

and my fstab entry for the drives are

```
# /media/Data_Ext4 was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=1c2862cf-5838-49a7-bcef-715319a7841e /media/Data_Ext4 ext4    defaults,nofail,uid=1000       0       0

# /media/NTFS was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=4A94A52994A51889  /media/NTFS     ntfs    defaults,uid=1000                             0       0
```

but still uid=1001 can access these drives as mounted volumes....

Comment: ... and what about the group? Have you tried adding `gid=1000`?

Comment: ading gid=1000 lead to error during mounting

Comment: Perhaps `gid=119` would have been a better idea. 119 is the `admin` group

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the mount command does not have a Set UID permission set on it. A set UID permission allows a script to execute as the creator instead of the invoker. Lets say root owns/created the file, if you run it and it has that permission you're effectively root.

By changing this permission normal users can't use mount without sudo.

Comment: tried changing using chmod 0641 for /bin/mount ....no effect

Comment: ls -la, see if the change took properly, mount shouldn't have any types of odd background or font color if it did.

Comment: ls -la /bin/mount
-rw-r----x 1 root root 88716 2011-08-09 21:45 /bin/mount

Comment: Notice that last X on there? chmod anything as a 1 and that sets executable. You want 4 or 0 for readonly or no access.

Remember this goes back to binary:

RWX
000 = none;
001 = execute only;
100 = dec 4, readonly;

Just remember that.